# Copy yml file IFF it's is in GITHub Actions - CI/CD

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm using a `config.yml` file in dev and in prod to store `env` value. When I check in my python code, GITHub Actions builds the image and runs the pytests.

Now - I do NOT commit the `config.yml` file in github code directory, because the environmental variables (e.g. like other API endpoint services: https://service_1.mydomain.com) are different for each environment - and thus I don't want it to overwrite the existing `config.yml` file.

However, what do you recommend for GITHub Actions where it builds the image and runs the pytests and there is NO `config.yml` file? Is there a "copy if it does not exist command for the dockerfile?

(Assume I don't want to mock the `config.yml` as a given dict)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way:

1. Add a copy of the config.yml into the `tests` folder where your test file is.
2. Read that config.yml and have it returned where you read in the config.yml file from the original path.

Done.

```
path = Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute().joinpath("tests/config.yml")
with open(path, 'r') as stream:
   try:
       cfg_dict=yaml.safe_load(stream)
       print(pfm_dict)
   except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
       print(exc)
   mocker.patch("utils.get_config_file", return_value=cfg_dict)
```